# Would I need to sharpen a knife if I hone it often?

Tags: knives

I am new to this knife maintenance buisness, and would like to ask the question in title. If I regularly hone my knife, and if the knife is decent quality, could I skip ever thinking of sharpening it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eventually all knives will need re-sharpening, once honing is not enough to return the edge.

The quality of the knife's steel, sharpness at the start* and skill or precision of the honing mechanism may determine how long this would be.

*I have many times found new knives aren't as sharp as I would like them & therefore they go straight into the sharpener, if not before first use, then soon after. [I get the feeling that this is not because they're not actually sharp, but the micro-burr is too smooth for my liking.]

Comment: And how long is this period till knife sharpening

Comment: See paragraph 2. you'll have to try it to find out.

Comment: Well, I mean roughly speaking

Comment: There really is no 'roughly speaking'. As already stated, it depends on the hardness of the steel, amount of use it gets, also whether you have a good chopping board or one that will damage the blade edge [glass, bamboo etc] & how well it's honed each time.

Comment: I hone mine every 2-3 uses, and sharpen them around once a year, if that helps.  That's high-end (Henkels) knives used exclusively on wooden cutting boards.  I'm non-meat, so I never cut bone.