# To hone and then sharpen or sharpen and then hone?

Tags: knives

I have a dull knife, and want to get it sharp. My question is, do I sharpen and then hone it, or do I hone it and then sharpen it?

Comment: Please use search before posting - https://cooking.stackexchange.com/search?q=sharpen+hone Also, please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hey, Reine, can you explain how this question is distinct from your other question?  https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/125417/would-i-need-to-sharpen-a-knife-if-i-hone-it-often

Comment: This is about the sequence of improving the knife @FuzzyChef

Comment: What is the point of down voting this question, other than to discourage the asking of questions? See the following for my position on why we should stop down voting questions: https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3733/why-have-the-option-to-downvote-a-question

Comment: Yeah, we should only be downvoting questions if they're obnoxious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You sharpen the blade, and then hone it.

This depends somewhat on the sharpening method; some sharpeners don't need a honing step afterwards, and some do.  For example, my Japanese 6000-grit sharpening stone does not require honing after.  But a [pull-through sharpener](https://www.boroughkitchen.com/blogs/news/which-is-best-for-sharpening-a-knife-whetstones-sharpening-steels-or-pull-through-sharpeners) would require it.

Then hone it every 2-3 uses until it needs sharpening again.

Comment: Unless of course the blade is obviously badly aligned, then I would hone it first, so you don’t end up removing as much when sharpening it